# checking az cli output to see if a value is returned

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I have got the code below which works fine, however the way in which I am checking if a vnet pairing is found is somewhat wrong.

This is what the code looks like.

```
  $existing_peering = az network vnet peering show -g 'xx' -n 'ccc' --vnet-name 'ccc'

      if ($existing_peering) {
          write-output 'Peering exists'
   
      }
```

The output of `$existing_peering` is as follows.

```
{
  "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
  "allowGatewayTransit": true,
  "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
  "doNotVerifyRemoteGateways": false,
  "etag": "W/\"xxxxxx\"",
  "id": "/subscriptions/fdfd",
  "name": "xxxx",
  "peeringState": "Disconnected",
  "peeringSyncLevel": "FullyInSync",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "remoteAddressSpace": {
    "addressPrefixes": [
      "10.77.0.0/16"
    ]
  },
  "remoteBgpCommunities": null,
  "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
    "id": "/subscriptions/",
    "resourceGroup": "my-rg"
  },
  "remoteVirtualNetworkAddressSpace": {
    "addressPrefixes": [
      "10.77.0.0/16"
    ]
  },
  "remoteVirtualNetworkEncryption": null,
  "resourceGroup": "cccc",
  "resourceGuid": "ggggggggggg",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
  "useRemoteGateways": false
}
```

I would like to get the value of `name` and the way the if statement has been evaluated, i am not sure if this is the correct way, sometimes I find that if AZ cli cannot find an object, the value if `$existing_peering` could be an error message rather than the expected returned object, and when the `IF` statement is valuated, it could be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: You can use `ConvertFrom-Json` to turn it into an object you can dot source your way through since it returns text in JSON format: `$existing_peering = az network .... | ConvertFrom-Json` then, `$existing_peering.Name`. On a separate note, you could just use the PowerShell equivalent command of `Get-AzVirtualNetwork` if you have the module installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created virtual network and peered vnet  with the name of `vnet1-vnet2` like below:

[image]

To get the value of only `name` you can make use of below command:

```c
$existing_peering = az network vnet peering show -g "<RGName>" -n "<PeeredvnetName>" --vnet-name "<VnetName>" --query "name" --output tsv

if ($existing_peering) {
    Write-Output "Peering exists: $existing_peering"
} else {
    Write-Output "Peering does not exist"
}
```

***Output***:

[image]

Or as suggested by *Abraham Zinala*, you can use `ConvertFrom-Json` to turn it into an object by modifying script like below:

```c
$existing_peerings = az network vnet peering show -g "xxxx" -n "xxxx" --vnet-name "xxx" | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($peering_info in $existing_peerings) {
    if ($peering_info.name) {
        Write-Output 'Peering exists'
        # You can access other properties like $peering_info.name here
    }
}
```

***Output***:

[image]